# how to use the filters and exclude_ids parameters in facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to use the filters and exclude_ids parameters with this code?

```
$app_id = "1111111111111111";

     $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/";

     $message = "come join this app?";

     $requests_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&message=" . $message;

     if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
<?php 
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";
$message = "Would you like to join me in this great app?";
$exclude_ids = "XXXXXX"; // comma separated: aaaaaa,bbbbbb
$filters = array(
    //'app_users',
    array(
        'name' => 'Best friends',
        'user_ids' => 'XXXXXX,YYYYYY,ZZZZZZ'
    )
);

$requests_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
    . "&message=" . $message
    . "&exclude_ids=" . $exclude_ids
    . "&filters=" . json_encode($filters);

if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo "Request Ids: ";
    print_r($_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
}
?>
```

Here I'm *creating* a list of friends called "Best friends" and then excluding one user from it. Please refer to the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) documentation for filters options.

Comment: the filter parameter is working very well but the exclude_ids is not,  &exclude_ids=1111111111,222222222,3333333333